# Applying highlighting effect to text through replace() (Django 2.1)

Tags: html, css, django, replace

I am writing a custom template filter that highlights the keyword put into the search engine in the search results page, just like in Google search results.

Code for custom filter:

```
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
@stringfilter
def highlight(value, search_term):
    return value.replace(search_term, "<span class='highlight'>%s</span>" % search_term)
```

The filter doesn't change the targeted word's CSS class into `<span class='highlight'>`. Instead, the output displayed text in the browser is literally `<span class='highlight'>word</span>`. E.g. "The most desired car brand right now is `<span class='highlight'>Tesla</span>`." How can I make it so that the `replace()` method actually changes the CSS class of the targeted word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you need to autoscape when you filter makes changes to HTML elements https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping

Working code:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.html import conditional_escape
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(needs_autoescape=True)
@stringfilter
def highlight(value, search_term, autoescape=True):
    return mark_safe(value.replace(search_term, "<span class='highlight'>%s</span>" % search_term))
```